# Cómo exportar una base de datos mysql con phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hola quisiera saber cómo puedo exportar una base de datos mysql correctamente desde phpMyadmin.

Cuando digo correctamente me refiero únicamente a los caracteres, cuando he intentado exportar bases de datos con todos los registros (es decir no sólo la estructura)

Me refiero a esta pantalla de phpMyadmin

[image: Pantalla de phpMyAdmin]

Cuando exporto los registros que tienen "ñ" o letras con tildes, en lugar de estos caractéres, aparecene los unicode de estos, cómo puedo hacerlo correctamente.

Comment: La verdad no se esto funcionaría pero podes probar cambiando el dropdown de conjunto de caracteres del archivo a, por ejemplo ISO-8859-1, a ver que pasa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola porque seleccionas personalizado, sencillamente utiliza la exportación rápida y listo si es en formato sql al importar la bbdd mantiene la integridad de los datos y su formato.

Answer (score 1):

lo que estás preguntando en caso de mysql se llama "cotejamiento", y para no perder datos y que estos no se desconfiguren al cambiar de una base de datos a otra, te recomiendo usar siempre el cotejamiento llamado:

```
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci'
```